# Loadpicture giving Runtime-error 481: Invalid picture

Tags: vb6

I have a project which copy varbinary(max) image data from sql server to msaccess ole object and when I am trying to bind that images to image control of VB6 its giving Runtime-error 481: Invalid picture, also I tried saving those msaccess images and they are getting saved fine but when I am trying to load those images in image control they are giving same error, following is my code and attach is my image file

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("f:\tttt111.jpeg")
End Sub
```

Following is the url to download image
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e2d4a91143507b3522bdd6632d69aa8b20161214051703/ae44f7

Comment: If it a really a proper JPEG format image you probably just wrote it to disk incorrectly and corrupted it.

Comment: Link seems to be dead? You could add the image directly into your question

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using a PNG file and that is not supported by VB6. The supported formats are Bitmap, Icon, Cursor, Metafile, JPEG, and GIF. [More info here...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242027%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Try converting the image to JPEG and it'll work.

Comment: Actually image is jpeg but when I uploaded to stackoverflow they changed the extension to png, you can download the image using following url. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e2d4a91143507b3522bdd6632d69aa8b20161214051703/ae44f7

Comment: @Amandeep It is a PNG file with a JPEG extension. You can check for yourself by uploading your file here http://www.checkfiletype.com/

Answer (score 0):

We've had WIA 2.0 for a long time now.  Here the database data is simulated by reading the file bytes:

```
Option Explicit
'
'Reference to: Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0
'

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim F As Integer
    Dim Bytes() As Byte

    'Get data into Byte array:
    F = FreeFile(0)
    Open "oBSkm.png" For Binary Access Read As #F
        ReDim Bytes(LOF(F) - 1)
    Get #F, , Bytes
    Close #F

    With New WIA.Vector
        .BinaryData = Bytes
        Image1.Picture = .Picture
    End With

    With New WIA.ImageFile
        .LoadFile "oBSkm.png"
        Image2.Picture = .FileData.Picture
    End With
End Sub
```

Preinstalled as part of Windows Vista and later.  Was once available as an SDK with documentation and a redist version to be installed into Windows XP SP1 or later but no longer provided by Microsoft.  You snooze, you lose.

Comment: actually its a jpeg image not png, you can download image using following url - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e2d4a91143507b3522bdd6632d69aa8b20161214051703/ae44f7

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but I am happy I found working solution. The source of this issue for me was image dimensions was too large than image control I was trying to place image on, So All I had to do is change the image dimensions from 500 X 500 to 200 X 200 and error 481 in vba excel (invalid picture) was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

By my experience, MS Access Loadpicture has problems with anything else but gif format.